# Specify worksheet in XSLT export filter for OpenOffice Calc

Tags: xml, xslt, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I'm using XSLT export filter to extract part of my OpenOffice Calc file into an XML file. I based my filter on the second answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817081/convert-calcexcel-data-in-xml-in-openoffice) and it worked fine until I added another Worksheet to the Calc file.

Now the filter is applied to every worksheet and as those are quite different the resulting XML is garbage.

Can I specify which worksheet to apply the filter to when exporting? Like by using the name or the order position of the sheet?

Edit:

The excel looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ilSp.jpg).

As you can see there is also a second worksheet which I want to apply another XSLT filter to.

Currently the filter for the table in the screenshot looks like this (it works fine when there is only one spreadsheet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="office table text">

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <command name="CreateTitle">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/office:body" />
  </command>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="office:body">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="office:spreadsheet">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="office:spreadsheet/table:table">
    <title><xsl:value-of select="table:table-row[2]/table:table-cell[1]/text:p" /></title> 
    <titleDesc><xsl:value-of select="table:table-row[2]/table:table-cell[2]/text:p" /></titleDesc>
    <institute><xsl:value-of select="table:table-row[2]/table:table-cell[3]/text:p" /></institute>   
    <contractType><xsl:value-of select="table:table-row[2]/table:table-cell[4]/text:p" /></contractType>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That's the input format: http://pastebin.com/tLyFKU4e (kinda long)

Comment: Try changing `<xsl:template match="office:body"><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:template>` to `<xsl:template match="office:body"><xsl:apply-templates select="office:spreadsheet[1]"/></xsl:template>` as an attempt to process based on position. I am not familiar with the XML format of OpenOffice so try on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that sadly didn't work. I also tried to google for this kind of syntax but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Does changing `<xsl:apply-templates select="office:spreadsheet[1]"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::office:spreadsheet[1]"/>` improve things? As I said, I am not familiar with the exact XML format so unless you edit the question and show us an input sample it is guessing.

Comment: Sadly that also didn't help (the resulting XML is empty). I edited in some more information which I hope may help.

Comment: Try to write a simple stylesheet solely doing `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>`, then you should see the input format and you can post that

Comment: Ah, now I understood, sorry. I edited a link to the input format into the end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears a `spreadsheet` elements contains various `table` children so if you only want to process the first table (assuming it represents the first worksheet) then use

```
<xsl:template match="office:body">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="office:spreadsheet/table:table[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

together with your other templates setting up a root element and of course the one extracting the data from the table

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <command name="CreateTitle">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/office:body" />
  </command>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="office:spreadsheet/table:table">
    <title><xsl:value-of select="table:table-row[2]/table:table-cell[1]/text:p" /></title> 
    <titleDesc><xsl:value-of select="table:table-row[2]/table:table-cell[2]/text:p" /></titleDesc>
    <institute><xsl:value-of select="table:table-row[2]/table:table-cell[3]/text:p" /></institute>   
    <contractType><xsl:value-of select="table:table-row[2]/table:table-cell[4]/text:p" /></contractType>
 </xsl:template>
```